# will i be charged by AWS S3 if i upload 1GB file and then delete it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

i know about Free tier, but i want to create website where any uploaded file will be deleted after 10 minutes.

how much i will be charged for keeping 1GB file on AWS s3. is keeping file saved for 10 minutes on AWS is same as keeping it there for one month.

is S3  best for temporary hosting data, or is there any better alternative with less charges.

Comment: In free tier you have 5 GB of S3 for free.

Comment: i know about free tier, but i want to buy S3 after clearing these doubts.

Comment: At `$0.023 per GB`, it would cost 2.3c if it was kept there for a month. Even if it was charged for an hour, that would only be $0.000032. I wouldn't be too worried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will be charged without a free-tier. 10 minutes will be **rounded up to 1 hour**, as S3 charges are per [byte-hour](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#Billing).